# How do I save and restore multiple variables in python?

Tags: python, variables, object

I need to save about a dozen objects to a file and then restore them later.
I've tried to use a for loop with pickle and shelve but it didn't work right.

Edit.
All of the objects that I was trying to save were in the same class (I should have mentioned this before), and I didn't realize that I could just save the whole class like this:

```
import pickle
def saveLoad(opt):
    global calc
    if opt == "save":
        f = file(filename, 'wb')
        pickle.dump(calc, f, 2)
        f.close
        print 'data saved'
    elif opt == "load":
        f = file(filename, 'rb')
        calc = pickle.load(f)
    else:
        print 'Invalid saveLoad option'
```

Comment: You say you've tried a for loop. Please post that code, and why "it didn't work right" (i.e., what happened and what you wanted to happen).

Comment: If you are on windows, make sure to open the files in binary mode

Comment: @gnibbler: binary mode is only needed for the non-default protocols (http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#usage).

Answer (score 226):

If you need to save multiple objects, you can simply put them in a single list, or tuple, for instance:

```
import pickle

# obj0, obj1, obj2 are created here...

# Saving the objects:
with open('objs.pkl', 'w') as f:  # Python 3: open(..., 'wb')
    pickle.dump([obj0, obj1, obj2], f)

# Getting back the objects:
with open('objs.pkl') as f:  # Python 3: open(..., 'rb')
    obj0, obj1, obj2 = pickle.load(f)
```

If you have a lot of data, you can reduce the file size by passing `protocol=-1` to `dump()`; `pickle` will then use the best available protocol instead of the default historical (and more backward-compatible) protocol.  In this case, the file must be opened in binary mode (`wb` and `rb`, respectively).

The binary mode should also be used with Python 3, as its default protocol produces binary (i.e. non-text) data (writing mode `'wb'` and reading mode `'rb'`).

Comment: In Python 3.5, I had to open the file in "byte" mode, e.g. `with open('objs.pickle', 'wb') as f:` (note the `wb`).

Comment: Hi @Eric, what is the need of `with open('objs.pkl') as f:` compare to simply `obj1, obj2 = pickle.load(open("objs.pkl","rb"))` ? Is there any difference between these two?

Comment: With the second form you do not close the file. This is not considered good practice, as the number of files that you can be opened in parallel is usually quite limited by the operating systems (try a loop that opens files without closing them!). That said, in practice, not closing the file often works, when you don't open many files.

Answer (score 60):

There is a built-in library called [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html). Using [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) you can dump objects to a file and load them later.

```
import pickle

f = open('store.pckl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(obj, f)
f.close()

f = open('store.pckl', 'rb')
obj = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

Comment: I Python 3.4 use: `f = open('store.pckl', 'wb')` to open a file to write to.  Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906623/using-pickle-dump-typeerror-must-be-str-not-bytes  And use `f = open('store.pckl', 'rb') to open a file to read from.  Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031699/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface.

Comment: is this specific to 3.4+? I almost voted the answer down because it generates errors when you don't use 'b'.

Comment: The question was "How do I save and restore multiple variables in python?"
Please update your answer how to handle multiple variables in a pickle, instead of one variable.

Answer (score 14):

Another approach to saving multiple variables to a pickle file is:

```
import pickle

a = 3; b = [11,223,435];
pickle.dump([a,b], open("trial.p", "wb"))

c,d = pickle.load(open("trial.p","rb"))

print(c,d) ## To verify
```

Comment: This does not safely close the files. `open` makes a file handle that needs to be closed either by storing the handle and calling `.close` on it, or preferably by using `with open(...) as ...:`. The second option is generally better as it will close the file automatically for you, even if an exception occurs.

Answer (score 13):

You should look at the [shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) and [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) modules. If you need to store a lot of data it may be better to use a database

Comment: I want to save a single object which logins into a cloud server, in order to handle if I login multiple times over time, the server rejects my request. Does dumping an object into a file using pickle module may have any security issue? , for example where if someone obtain my dumped object, than they can login into my cloud-storage without using a password.

Answer (score 9):

The following approach seems simple and can be used with variables of different size:

```
import hickle as hkl
# write variables to filename [a,b,c can be of any size]
hkl.dump([a,b,c], filename)

# load variables from filename
a,b,c = hkl.load(filename)
```

Comment: `hickle` package is more robust (less error prone) and even simpler (less code) than `pickle`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `klepto`, which provides persistent caching to memory, disk, or database.

```
dude@hilbert>$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 12 2013, 13:26:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from klepto.archives import file_archive
>>> db = file_archive('foo.txt')
>>> db['1'] = 1
>>> db['max'] = max
>>> squared = lambda x: x**2
>>> db['squared'] = squared
>>> def add(x,y):
...   return x+y
... 
>>> db['add'] = add
>>> class Foo(object):
...   y = 1
...   def bar(self, x):
...     return self.y + x
... 
>>> db['Foo'] = Foo
>>> f = Foo()
>>> db['f'] = f  
>>> db.dump()
>>>
```

Then, after interpreter restart...

```
dude@hilbert>$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 12 2013, 13:26:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from klepto.archives import file_archive
>>> db = file_archive('foo.txt')
>>> db
file_archive('foo.txt', {}, cached=True)
>>> db.load()
>>> db
file_archive('foo.txt', {'1': 1, 'add': <function add at 0x10610a0c8>, 'f': <__main__.Foo object at 0x10510ced0>, 'max': <built-in function max>, 'Foo': <class '__main__.Foo'>, 'squared': <function <lambda> at 0x10610a1b8>}, cached=True)
>>> db['add'](2,3)
5
>>> db['squared'](3)
9
>>> db['f'].bar(4)
5
>>>
```

Get the code here:
  https://github.com/uqfoundation

Comment: The OP didn't ask for built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using dill (https://dill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dill.html) package.
Pickle should work similarly.

```
""" Some objects to save """

import numpy as np
a = 6
b = 3.5
c = np.linspace(2,5,11)

""" Test the dump part """

import dill
file_name = 'dill_dump_test_file.dil'
list_of_variable_names = ('a', 'b', 'c')

with open(file_name,'wb') as file:
    dill.dump(list_of_variable_names, file)  # Store all the names first
    for variable_name in list_of_variable_names:
        dill.dump(eval(variable_name), file) # Store the objects themselves
        
#   Clear all the variables here     

""" Test the load part """

import dill
file_name = 'dill_dump_test_file.dil'
g = globals()

with open(file_name,'rb') as file:
    list_of_variable_names = dill.load(file)  # Get the names of stored objects
    for variable_name in list_of_variable_names:
        g[variable_name] = dill.load(file)    # Get the objects themselves
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).