#  TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python

i post from my original code,

```
crystal = open('vmises.dat','r')
crystalincrement  = pickle.load(crystal)
crystaldir = pickle.load(crystal)
crystalface = pickle.load(crystal)
crystal.close()
```

Error is,

```
crystalincrement  = pickle.load(crystal)
```

TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

i use python V 3.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question was edited after I originally posted this and it was accepted. The answer to the updated question is to open the file in binary mode:

```
crystal = open('vmises.dat', 'rb')
```

---

Answer to original, pre-edit question:

Well, `data` is a string. The object you need to work on is `a`.

```
a = open('data.txt','r')
b = pickle.load(a) 
c = pickle.load(a)
d = pickle.load(a)
a.close()
```

For `pickle` info, see the [Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle) or [Python for Kids](https://python4kids.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/an-awful-pickle/).

Comment: If someone has trouble with the docs, it doesn't help to point them somewhere else that uses the same language to describe the material. You need to point them somewhere that will describe it differently.

Comment: I guess we need to be honest at that point and admit we're just a glorified search engine service.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers. We're here to search for them. We have the expertise to search for the right thing. Sometimes we know surprising sources for info -- you were surprised by Python Kids, what makes you think he would have clicked on it even if he did the right Google Search?

Answer (score 15):

The real answer should be open the file in binary mode in windows. 
    open('data.txt', 'rb')

Answer (score 0):

The `pickle` module loads a pickled object, which is a serialized version of a Python object. This code is trying to load a serialized data set into your program. You can read more about this module here: http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

I don't know where you've defined the variable `data`, but you probably want to load from the variable `a`, which is the pointer to a file which pickle takes in, or rename that variable to `data`.

```
data = open('data.txt','r')
b = pickle.load(data)
c = pickle.load(data)
d = pickle.load(data)
data.close()
```

Comment: Now you're trying to call `.close()` on an object that doesn't exist. What line specifically throws the error, in which version of Python, does it have a stack trace? This is all information that would be helpful.