# Restore objects from pickled file by name in python

Tags: python, pickle

Using Python 2.7.
Is there a way to restore only specified objects from a pickle file?

using the same example as a [previous post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568007/how-do-i-save-and-restore-multiple-variables-in-python)

```
import pickle

# obj0, obj1, obj2 are created here...

# Saving the objects:
with open('objs.pickle', 'w') as f:
    pickle.dump([obj0, obj1, obj2], f)
```

Now, I would like to only restore, say, obj1

I am doing the following:

```
with open('objs.pickle', 'r') as f:
    obj1=pickle.load(f)[1]
```

but let's say I don't know the order of objects, just it's name.
Writing this, I am guessing the names get dropped during pickling?

Comment: you can use different files for the different objects or pickle a list and store an index in another file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of storing the objects in a list, you could use a dictionary to provide names for each object:

```
import pickle

s = pickle.dumps({'obj0': obj0, 'obj1': obj1, 'obj2': obj2})

obj1 = pickle.loads(s)['obj1']
```

The order of the items no longer matters, in fact there is no order because a dictionary is being restored.

I'm not 100% sure that this is what you wanted. Were you hoping to restore the object of interest only, i.e. without parsing and restoring the other objects? I don't think that can be done with pickles without writing your own parser, or a fair degree of hacking.

Answer (score 3):

No. Python objects do not have "names" (besides some exceptions like *functions* and *classes* that know their declared names), the names are just pointing to the object, and an object does not know its name even at runtime, and thus cannot be persisted in a pickle either.

Perhaps you need [a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373185/918959) instead.