# TensorFlow saver - Saving an ordinary Python variable

Tags: tensorflow

When using TensorFlow Saver, is there a way to save an ordinary Python variable as well?

If not, what is the best solution when certain Python vars are helpful to save.

Answer (score 1):

You can save/restore python variables with [pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6568859/1090562).

```
import pickle

f = open('store.pckl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(your_var, f)
f.close()

f = open('store.pckl', 'rb')
your_var = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```