# write and read lists from/to file in python

Tags: python, numpy, file, format, dtype

How to write, then read, (conserving all specifics) of the following list, in python?

Using various methods, I could not read the data back with the exact same formatting, datatypes, etc.  I'm using python 3.6.7.  Here is a toy-sample to play with

```
sample_list = [[np.ones(shape = (3,4), dtype='uint8'), np.int64(2), 'd654'], [np.ones(shape = (3,4), dtype='uint8'), np.int64(4), 'd654']]
```

Comment: Have you tried `pickle`?

Comment: No.  That seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import Pickle:

```
import pickle
```

Save Variable:

```
f = open('store.pckl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(sample_list, f)
f.close()
```

Load Variable:

```
f = open('store.pckl', 'rb')
obj = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6568495/3353760

**Update:** Using `numpy.save()`

```
import numpy as np
```

Save Variable:

```
np.save(file='sample_list', arr=sample_list)
```

Load Variable:

```
np.load('sample_list.npy', allow_pickle=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, pickled failed to save to file due to "MemoryError: ".  I postulate that the data to be save was too big so I used:

    np.save('X',X) 
    np.load('X.npy')

Comment: Right. 'np.save()' works better with saving large matrices and loading them back into memory.

Comment: I'm not on my computer now, feel free to update the answer. Else I'll do it later...